# Outlook msg files stored in local disk, how to read with delphi

Tags: delphi, com, outlook

I need to retrieve the body of outlooks' msg files stored on a local disk and extract some information from each one, their format is always the same only the data changes, please advise.

thanks in advance
Raul

---

Thanks to everybody,

due to the restriction to answer myself, I'll write my solution just below my question.

I've checked some MS documentation and here is my solution working as expected.

```
procedure TForm1.displayOutlookMsg(aFileName: string);
const
olFormatHTML = 2;
olFormatPlain = 1;
olFormatRichText = 3 ;
olFormatUnspecified = 0;

var outlook: OleVariant;
    outlookMsg, bodyMsg: variant;
begin

  try
    Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  except
    Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  end;

  outlookMsg:= outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(aFileName);
  outlookMsg.bodyFormat := olFormatPlain;

  bodyMsg:= outlookMsg.body;

  Memo1.Lines.Add(VarToStr(bodyMsg));
  outlook:= unassigned;

end;
```

Comment: You should make this an answer, then accept that answer. That will decrease your unaccepted answers count and improve the overall StackOverflow quality: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A548280+is%3Aanswer+hasaccepted%3Ano

Answer (score 2):

Raul,  you can parse the msg files yourself checking the [`Outlook MSG file format`](http://www.fileformat.info/format/outlookmsg/) or using a Delphi component like [`SMMsg suite`](http://www.scalabium.com/msg/msglib.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You could try [SMMsg](http://www.scalabium.com/msg/msglib.htm) from Scalabium.